Expand tiers in currency_options for Stripe prices
I need to retrieve a price using Stripe API with the tiers, currency_options and tiers inside the currency_options. The following CLI command does return tiers at the root object and currency_options, but not tiers inside the currency_options. Why is that?
I do see the tiers for the currencies in the dashboard for this price.
stripe prices retrieve X \
-d "expand[0]"=tiers \
-d "expand[1]"=currency_options.data.tiers

Returns:
{
  "id": "X",
  "object": "price",
  "active": true,
  "billing_scheme": "tiered",
  "created": 1717060175,
  "currency": "eur",
  "currency_options": {
    "eur": {
      "custom_unit_amount": null,
      "tax_behavior": "exclusive",
      "unit_amount": null,
      "unit_amount_decimal": null
    },
    "usd": {
      "custom_unit_amount": null,
      "tax_behavior": "exclusive",
      "unit_amount": null,
      "unit_amount_decimal": null
    }
  },
  "custom_unit_amount": null,
  "livemode": false,
  "lookup_key": null,
  "metadata": {},
  "nickname": null,
  "product": "X",
  "recurring": {
    "aggregate_usage": null,
    "interval": "month",
    "interval_count": 1,
    "meter": null,
    "trial_period_days": null,
    "usage_type": "licensed"
  },
  "tax_behavior": "exclusive",
  "tiers": [
    {
      "flat_amount": null,
      "flat_amount_decimal": null,
      "unit_amount": 1500,
      "unit_amount_decimal": "1500",
      "up_to": 10
    },
    {
      "flat_amount": null,
      "flat_amount_decimal": null,
      "unit_amount": 1200,
      "unit_amount_decimal": "1200",
      "up_to": null
    }
  ],
  "tiers_mode": "volume",
  "transform_quantity": null,
  "type": "recurring",
  "unit_amount": null,
  "unit_amount_decimal": null
}

EDIT : it seems to work by expanding specific currencies as currency_options is technically not a list, but an object whose properties is the currency code, and the value is the currency option, like this:
stripe prices retrieve X \
-d "expand[0]"=tiers \
-d "expand[1]"=currency_options.usd.tiers
-d "expand[2]"=currency_options.eur.tiers

But this is obviously not really practical as it requires to know, before the request, which currencies will be in currency_options. The solution would be to make a first request to know the currencies, and a second one to expand each currency, but it seems that a better solution should exist, isn't there any?

Yes unfortunately as opposed to array objects where we have the data expansion parameter Stripe doesn't offer the same for dynamic properties.
